# discord.py command not working after I add @commands.cooldown decorator

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot with a "find" command that has a cooldown of 120 seconds, but after I added in the cooldown decorator, the "find" command doesn't work anymore.

Here's my code:

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import json
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import cooldown, CommandOnCooldown
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType

load_dotenv()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="nut ")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("with nuts "))
    print("Logged in as {0.user}".format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower() == "nut":
        global r
        r = random.randint(1,3)
        if r == 1:
            await message.add_reaction("\N{CHESTNUT}")
        if r == 2:
            await message.add_reaction("\N{NUT AND BOLT}")
        if r == 3:
            await message.add_reaction("\N{PEANUTS}")

for filename in os.listdir(r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\programs\NutBot\cogs"):
     if filename.endswith(".py"):
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

My only cog is:

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import json
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import cooldown, CommandOnCooldown
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType

class Currency(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 120, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def find(self, ctx):
        global r
        r = int(float(random.randint(1,100))/2)
        if r == 0:
            return await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="You suck, you didn't find any nuts.", color=0xe0ad53))
        if r == 1:
            return await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="You found a nut!", color=0xe0ad53))
        if r == 50:
            return await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="You found 50 nuts! Woah...", color=0xe0ad53))
        else:
            return await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="You found " + str(r) + " nuts!", color=0xe0ad53))

    @find.error
    async def find_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Woah slow down, buddy.", description = "Your puny body is still recovering from the last expedition. You should rest for {int(error.retry_after)} more seconds.", color=0xd60000))

    @commands.command()
    async def search(self, ctx):
        await find.invoke(ctx)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Currency(bot))
```

‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 120, commands.BucketType.user)
async def find(ctx):
    global r
    r = int(float(random.randint(1,100))/2)
    if r == 0:
        return await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="You suck, you didn't find any nuts.", color=0xe0ad53))
    if r == 1:
        return await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="You found a nut!", color=0xe0ad53))
    if r == 50:
        return await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="You found 50 nuts! Woah...", color=0xe0ad53))
    else:
        return await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="You found " + str(r) + " nuts!", color=0xe0ad53))

@find.error
async def find_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Woah slow down, buddy.", description = "Your puny body is still recovering from the last expedition. You should rest for {int(error.retry_after)} more seconds.", color=0xd60000))
```

There are some things to note here, add `return await` in all conditions (I tried this in my bot and it actually sent me the message twice when I only ran it once. Your main command has no issue.

Your error handler may not work as you wanted it to though.
`description = "Your puny body is still recovering from the last expedition. You should rest for {:.2f} more seconds.` this line does not use a `f'string` (meaning you will see {:.2f} as it is}

Even `f'string` was added, you will get an error. Use this `int(error.retry_after)` [This will show the seconds left for the cooldown.]

Besides this, I see no other errors with your code.

Comment: I'm new to this stuff and sorry if this is a dumb question, but why use return await instead of await?

Comment: After doing what you told me to, "find" still doesn't make the bot say anything, but taking out "@commands.cooldown" makes it work again if that helps.

Comment: Add me on discord UnidentifiedComponent#8118 and send an invite to your test server